# asp.net Core 3.1.5 app cannot access database on server from web deploy publish

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `Blazor Web Assembly` app which I have publishing to a server running `Windows Server 2019` with the database on `MSSQL Server 2019 Express Edition`.

The web app is using `AspNetCore 3.1.5` with `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.5`. Locally the app runs fine through self-hosting and IIS Express through Visual Studio 2019.

I can also run migrations to the servers database and seed using the following connection string through the PCM using `update-database`;

```
"Data Source=IPADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated
Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User
ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

however after I publish the app to the server, when I attempt to log into the app i receive the following error;

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

the only difference to the connection string on publish is that the IP become local host in my appsettings.release.json;

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

For completeness I have also attempted to add in the port number to the connection string;

```
"Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

Finally I can confirm I can login with the same credentials using MSSQL Management Studio with localhost with RDP on the server.

I also attached the about info from management studio for information;

[image: management studio screenshot]

**EDIT Updated Information**

Following on from comments below here is a screenshot of the SQL Configuration Manager;

[image: sql server configuration manager screenshot]

[image: sql server configuration manager screenshot 2]

[image: sql server configuration manager screenshot 3]

Can anyone direct me as to why its not connecting?

Comment: Do you specify only `localhost` for the successful SSMS connection?

Comment: @DanGuzman I used the IP Address for the successful remote connection to the database (when running migrations and also I can see this through visual studio server object explorer) but also I have logged in successfully using MSSQL Management Studio (when RDP'ed into the server) using localhost with the same login creds?

Comment: If you can connect from SSMS specifying only `localhost` while RDPed into the server, I'd expect the app code to be able to connect too. The error suggests connectivity rather than credentials. Perhaps the deployed connection string is not as expected.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I this seems to look like a `Asp.Net Core` issue ro `EntityFrameworkCore` issue, From looking a the published `appsettings.release.json` all seems good. Also I have published a legacy application on `asp.net` which utilises localhost in a connection string and this is working just fine too.

Comment: On the web hosting server run up SQL Configuration Manager and check that you have the TCP/IP protocol enabled in the 32-bit and 64-bit Client Protocols categories and that TCP/IP is first in the protocol orders. Based on the error message it sounds like you have Named Pipes enabled but TCP/IP disabled, or Named Pipes has a lower order (higher priority) than TCP/IP.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have updated the question to include a screenshot of the SQL Configuration Manager, Named Pipes seems to be disabled?

Comment: 32bit and 64bit client protocols are configured separately, is it the same for 64bit? i.e.: SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration > Client Protocols?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry I missed uploading that screenshot. To confirm yes i is the same and I have updated above

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Ok, after restarting the MSSQL Service and IIS it has started connecting. I'd just like to thank you both for taking the time out to help and your time.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for your help and time also.